# Which of the following statement is true for assertions in java? why?

Tags: java

Which of the following statement is true for assertions in java? Why?

A. If assertions are compiled into a source file, and if no flags are included at runtime, assertions will execute by default.

B. As of Java version 1.4, assertion statements are compiled by default.

C. With the proper use of runtime arguments, it is possible to instruct the VM to disable assertions for a certain class, and to enable assertions for a certain package, at the same time.

D. When evaluating command-line arguments, the VM gives -ea flags precedence over -da flags.

Comment: Have you done any research into any of the answers?

Comment: I am new to java and this question i have come across one of the website... so would like to understand it.... I have not done any investigation on it...

Comment: @abcreddy Posting a question here shouldn't be the first step in your investigation. Searching for tutorials on the internet, asking a friend with the relevant knowledge, and so on should be the first step. Only after you've exhausted all those and *still* don't understand is it then the right time to post a question. We answerers are here to help you help yourself, and not to spew out answers so that you don't have to do any research on your own.

Answer (score 2):

A: Check the descriptions of the flags for your java executable.

B: Read up in [The Java 1.4 Feature Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/relnotes/features.html)

C: Again, the description of the flags. Check the output of `java -help` for starters.

D: Look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/assertions-139853.html) for primers.

E-Z: Do your homework yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SCJP dump question:
Per policy you should not be posintg such question here but anyways :)

Answer: Option C

Explanation:

Option C is true because multiple VM flags can be used on a single invocation of a Java program.

Option A is incorrect because at runtime assertions are ignored by default.

Option B is incorrect because as of Java 1.4 you must add the argument -source 1.4 to the command line if you want the compiler to compile assertion statements.

Option D is incorrect because the VM evaluates all assertion flags left to right.